# how to deploy expressjs application on window server

Tags: node.js, express, strongloop, pm2

There many tools to deploy expressjs application, such as **strongloop**,**pm2**.

But they do not work well on windows.

I have install [pm2]2 in my window computer, and start my app.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpOIa.jpg

But when i log off my computer and log in again. the  service is disappear.
So I install **pm2-windows-service** and install pm2 as a window service. It failed again.

Anyone have a good expressjs deployment plan？

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `pm2 save` when you started your app. PM2 need to know which apps were started and their state to restart them after a reboot, and thats the aim of the `pm2 save` command which will save the state of all apps in the pm2 directory.

Comment: I tried again and it still does not work. **dump.pm2** file has been generated.